# Firestore) how to update recyclerview after update data field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have recyclerview and there is a one button.
This button can change Boolean state from true to false, false to true.
And I want to change the button's background color according to its boolean state.

Below is my code

```kotlin
class ProjectFeedBigAdapter : ListAdapter<Project, ProjectFeedBigAdapter.ProjectFeedBigViewHolder>(
    ProjectFeedDiffUtil()
) {
    val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val projects: ArrayList<Project> = arrayListOf()

    init {
        db.collection("projects")
            .orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, exception ->
                projects.clear()

                if(querySnapshot == null) return@addSnapshotListener

                for(snapshot in querySnapshot.documents) {
                    val project = snapshot.toObject(Project::class.java)
                    projects.add(project!!)
                }
                submitList(projects)
            }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder...{...}

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectFeedBigViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)

        holder.apply {
            when(item.booleanState) {
                true -> {
                    // Button BackgroundColor Change
                }
                else -> {
                    // Button BackgroundColor Change
                }
            }

            stateButton.setOnClickListener {
                val project = db.collection("projects").document(item.projectId)

                item.booleanState?.let {
                    project
                        .update("booleanState", !it)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { Toast.makeText(//context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->  }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    inner class ProjectFeedBigViewHolder(private val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    ...
    }
}


class ProjectFeedDiffUtil: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Project>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Project, newItem: Project): Boolean {
        return oldItem.timeStamp == newItem.timeStamp
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Project, newItem: Project): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }

}
```

when I click 'stateButton',

1. Boolean state changes occur. (I can see the data is changing on Firebase Cloud)
2. Also, can see that pass the submitList().
3. But not enter onBindViewHolder, so stateButton's background color doesn't change.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you have notify your adapter that data has changed with `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: it's not the correct way updating as mentioned in Ashish answer, 'notifyDataSetChanged()' update whole list. So if you have 10 data it'll reload whole list. 
Don't recommended to make it if your data are updating in high frequency. 
If it's only very small list  maybe you can use it for proceeding your work.